# Unity3D : Retry Menu (Scene Management)

Tags: menu, unity-game-engine

I'm making a simple 2D game for Android using the Unity3D game engine. I created all the levels and everything but I'm stuck at making the game over/retry menu. So far I've been using new scenes as a game over menu. I used this simple script:

```
#pragma strict

var level = Application.LoadLevel;

function OnCollisionEnter(Collision : Collision)
{
    if(Collision.collider.tag == "Player")
    {
        Application.LoadLevel("GameOver");
    }
}
```

And this as a 'menu':

```
#pragma strict

var myGUISkin : GUISkin;

var btnTexture : Texture;

function OnGUI() {
GUI.skin = myGUISkin;


if (GUI.Button(Rect(Screen.width/2-60,Screen.height/2+30,100,40),"Retry"))
    Application.LoadLevel("Easy1");

if (GUI.Button(Rect(Screen.width/2-90,Screen.height/2+100,170,40),"Main Menu"))
    Application.LoadLevel("MainMenu");
}
```

The problem stands at the part where I have to create over 200 game over scenes, obstacles (the objects that kill the player) and recreate the same script over 200 times for each level. Is there any other way to make this faster and less painful?

Edit : If possible,please when you suggest your ideas,use javascript only,I don't understand C#,not even a little bit.I know Im asking too much but it realy confuses me.
Thank you.

Comment: It's not clear. Why do you need to create over 200 game over scenes and edit script over 200 times?

Comment: Because of this `Application.LoadLevel("Easy1");`?

Comment: I have over 200 levels in this game,I have/had to copy/paste them and edit each one of them to open a specific level.

Answer (score 1):

There are several different solutions, but I would recommend using PlayerPrefs.  This has the extra benefit of persisting even when the application is closed and then re-opened.

In your Awake() function of your Main Menu class, you can get the current level and store it in a static string of your Main Menu class.  If it is the player's 1st time, use the name for level 1.

Something like this:

```
static string currentLevelName;
void Awake()
{
    currentLevelName = PlayerPrefs.GetString("CurrentLevel");
    if (currentLevelName == defaultValue)
    {
       currentLevelName = "Level1"
    }
}
```

Then, modify your button to do this instead:

```
if (GUI.Button(Rect(Screen.width/2-60,Screen.height/2+30,100,40),"Retry"))
    Application.LoadLevel(currentLevelName);
```

Whenever the player advances to the next level, set the string in PlayerPrefs to the new level name:

```
PlayerPrefs.SetString("CurrentLevel", Application.loadedLevelName);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class with static properties. For example (in c#)

```cs
public class GameOverInput
{
    public static string name;
    public static string retryLevel;
    //all the info you need
}
```

Then you can easily read the input in your game over scene (only one is needed)

```cs
public class GameOverMenu : MonoBehavior
{
    void Start()
    {
        Debug.Log("You were killed by " + GameOverInput.name);
        Application.LoadLevel(GameOverInput.retryLevel);
    }
}
```

And you set this info just before loading the game over scene

```cs
if (Collision.collider.tag == "Player")
{
    GameOverInput.name = "Baddie";
    Application.LoadLevel("GameOver");
}
```

Comment: @SergeyKrusch and this is just an example anyway. Those languages aren't that different, hopefully OP can manage.

Comment: @LVBen That's why the input class isn't a MonoBehavior :)

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to make something like a singleton LevelManager MonoBehavior and add it to an object named "Level Manager".  Use the DontDestroyOnLoad function to make the object persist even when you load another level.

```
class LevelManager : MonoBehavior
{
    static LevelManager _instance;
    public string currentLevelName;
    public string killedBy;

    function Awake ()
    {
       if (_instance == null)
       {
          _instance = this;
           DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
       }
       else
       {
          Destroy(gameObject); // Make sure we never have more than 1 Level Manager.
       }
    }

    LevelManager Instance
    {
       get
       {
          if (_instance == null)
          {
             GameObject levelManagerObject = GameObject.Find("Level Manager");
             _instance = levelManagerObject.GetComponent<LevelManager>();
          }
          return _instance
       }
    }
}
```

Then, from the main menu class, you can always access the Level Manager like so:

```
Debug.Log("Killed by " + LevelManager.Instance.killedBy);
```

or

```
LevelManager.Instance.currentLevelName = Application.loadedLevelName;
```